# Revit API SetPointElementReference(PointOnPlane) - wrong workplane

Tags: revit-api

I try to create a family instance using CreateAdaptiveComponentInstance and try to host it on a reference point, that's also a control point of a CurveByPoints (spline).
The family links properly to the reference point, but the rotation of the reference point's workplane is totally ignored.

Try this standalone example. Move the reference point P2 -> The cross section at P1 will not rotate.
Now, rebuild and change the >> if(true) << to 'false'. Now you see what I want. But as soon as you move the point P2, the link between P2's coordinates and the family is broken.

```
        CurveByPoints spl = null;
        ReferencePointArray pts = null;
        // create ref points
        var p1 = doc.FamilyCreate.NewReferencePoint(new XYZ( 0, 0, 0)); p1.Name = "P1";
        var p2 = doc.FamilyCreate.NewReferencePoint(new XYZ(10,10, 0)); p2.Name = "P2";
        var p3 = doc.FamilyCreate.NewReferencePoint(new XYZ(30,20, 0)); p3.Name = "P3";
        pts = new ReferencePointArray();
        pts.Append(p1); pts.Append(p2); pts.Append(p3);
        // create a spline
        spl = doc.FamilyCreate.NewCurveByPoints(pts);
        spl.Visible = true;
        spl.IsReferenceLine = false; // MOdelliinie

        // change points to adaptive points
        foreach(ReferencePoint p in pts)
        {
            AdaptiveComponentFamilyUtils.MakeAdaptivePoint(doc, p.Id, AdaptivePointType.PlacementPoint);
            p.CoordinatePlaneVisibility = CoordinatePlaneVisibility.Always;
            p.ShowNormalReferencePlaneOnly = true;
        }

        // find an adaptive family to place at the points
        FamilySymbol fam_sym = null;
        var filter = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
        ICollection<Element> col = filter.OfClass(typeof(FamilySymbol)).ToElements();
        if(col!=null)
        {
            foreach(FamilySymbol ele in col)
            {
                if(ele == null || !AdaptiveComponentInstanceUtils.IsAdaptiveFamilySymbol(ele) ) {continue;}
                if(fam_sym == null)
                {
                    fam_sym=ele;
                }
                if(ele.Name == "profil_adapt_offset_einfach2") // use a special one instead of the first matching
                {
                    fam_sym = ele as FamilySymbol;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // create family instances
        if(fam_sym != null)
        {
            if(true) // this is waht I want. Try "false" to see what I expect
            {
                foreach (ReferencePoint p in pts)
                {
                    var inst = AdaptiveComponentInstanceUtils.CreateAdaptiveComponentInstance(doc, fam_sym);
                    var placements = AdaptiveComponentInstanceUtils.GetInstancePlacementPointElementRefIds(inst);
                    ReferencePoint fam_pt = doc.GetElement(placements.FirstOrDefault()) as ReferencePoint;

                    var pl = Plane.CreateByNormalAndOrigin(new XYZ(1,0,0), p.Position);

                    // #### I THINK HERE IS MY PROBLEM ####
                    // "plane" just points to the reference POINT,
                    // and not the XZ-PLANE of the reference point.
                    Reference plane = p.GetCoordinatePlaneReferenceYZ();

                    PointOnPlane pop = doc.Application.Create.NewPointOnPlane(plane, UV.Zero, UV.BasisU, 0.0);
                    fam_pt.SetPointElementReference(pop);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // create family instances and place along the path
                // -> looks good until you move a reference point
                double ltot=0.0;
                for(var i=0; i<pts.Size-1; ++i)
                {
                    ltot += pts.get_Item(i).Position.DistanceTo(pts.get_Item(i+1).Position);
                }

                double lfromstart=0;
                for(var i=0; i<pts.Size; ++i)
                {
                    if(i>0)
                    {
                        lfromstart += pts.get_Item(i).Position.DistanceTo(pts.get_Item(i-1).Position);
                    }
                    var inst = AdaptiveComponentInstanceUtils.CreateAdaptiveComponentInstance(doc, fam_sym);
                    var placements = AdaptiveComponentInstanceUtils.GetInstancePlacementPointElementRefIds(inst);

                    var location = new PointLocationOnCurve(PointOnCurveMeasurementType.NormalizedCurveParameter, lfromstart / ltot, PointOnCurveMeasureFrom.Beginning);
                    PointOnEdge po = doc.Application.Create.NewPointOnEdge(spl.GeometryCurve.Reference, location);
                    // attach first adaptive point to ref point
                    var firstPoint = doc.GetElement(placements.FirstOrDefault()) as ReferencePoint;
                    firstPoint.SetPointElementReference(po);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm using Revit 2018.2, here.

People might also search for: GetCoordinatePlaneReferenceXZ, GetCoordinatePlaneReferenceXY.

[edit1]

- NewReferencePoint() does not create SketchPlanes
- When I manually move a generated reference point -> Now the SketchPlane for this ReferencePoint is generated. But how create that with the API?

[edi2]
 - I found that e.g. manually changing the ReferencePoint.CoordinatePlaneVisibility=true will create the SketchPlane I need. But I can't do that in code:

```
        var sel = new List<ElementId>();
        foreach (ReferencePoint p in pts)
        {
            sel.Add(p.Id);
            // make plane visible
            p.CoordinatePlaneVisibility = CoordinatePlaneVisibility.Always;
            // shake point
            ElementTransformUtils.MoveElement(doc, p.Id, XYZ.BasisX);
            ElementTransformUtils.MoveElement(doc, p.Id, XYZ.BasisX.Negate());
        }
        ui_doc.Selection.SetElementIds(sel);
        doc.Regenerate();
        ui_doc.RefreshActiveView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Will it help if you use the `NewReferencePoint` overload taking a `Transform` argument, cf. [NewReferencePoint Method (Transform)](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018.1/c93b3173-1f70-be86-c4dc-4195de2e66a2.htm)? That might define the required plane for you and associate it with the point.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. NewReferencePoint(Transform) doesn't create a sketchplane. But I found out, that:
doc.Application.Create.NewPointOnPlane(plane, UV.Zero, UV.BasisU, 0.0);
finally does create a sketchplane. However, still the orientation of the family instance is not linked to the spline.

Comment: I discussed with the development team and we do not know how to reproduce this to analyse the behaviour. Please provide a complete minimal reproducible case -- http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#1b. Thank you!

Comment: Here's a detailed description and a test project:

[link](http://www.glbasic.com/beta/Revit-ReferencePointSketchPlane.zip)

Comment: Thank you! I passed it on to the devteam.

Answer (score 0):

The development team replied to your detailed description and test project provided in the attached ZIP file:

The developer seems to be in need of some API we haven’t exposed. PointElement’s API was written before RIDL, so the entire user interface is not exposed to the API. They need an API to get the reference plane that is normal to the the curve that it is driving. This plane is not the same as what is exposed by API `PointElement.GetCoordinatePlaneReferenceYZ()` (one among the three planes exposed to API).

As per `SketchPlanes` not being created (in the macro seen in the linked zip file), yes that is correct and matches the UI. SketchPlanes are elements and are different from `Autodesk.Revit.DB.Reference`. We don’t create them until we have to. And they get garbage collected too. At the end of description, I see some code that should work (assuming they wrapped it in a transaction). Normally selection of the point alone will trigger creation of the SketchPlane from the UI. That aside, I would still not recommend putting the point on SketchPlane for what they want to do.

While, what they want does not exist in API, it still does not quite mean there is no workaround for what they want to achieve. If the Selection or Reference API exposes selectable/visible references on an element, `Autodesk.Revit.DB.Reference`, then one can iterate over these and host the point. This is generic Element/Reference API.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thank you for this information. But I don't know what you mean by:
"If the Selection or Reference API exposes selectable/visible references on an element, Autodesk.Revit.DB.Reference, then one can iterate over these and host the point."

How can I iterate over these references? I can't see them in Snoop DB.